# Stepping through an array in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I've declared an uninitialized array in the data segment and I'm trying to take a users numeric input and store in the array. Here's a snippet of the code

```
arr          db          5 DUP(?), '$'

MOV CX,5

L1:
     LEA SI,X

     MOV AH,01
     INT 21H

     MOV [SI], AL
     INC SI
     LOOP L1
```

The reason I'm incrementing SI is because I want it to move on to the next index when the user inputs a value. I looked at the contents of the array after the user input and all it has done is overwrite the previous input and the rest left uninitialized. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

As always, use a debugger to single step your code and see where it goes wrong. In this case however it's obvious that looping back to `L1` will reload `SI` with the address of `X` so it will always store to the first item. Move the label after the initialization:

```
arr          db          5 DUP(?), '$'

     MOV CX,5
     LEA SI,X

L1:

     MOV AH,01
     INT 21H

     MOV [SI], AL
     INC SI
     LOOP L1
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this so unfortunately I wouldn't know how to debug it.

Comment: That's the first thing you should learn (well, right after you know how to create an executable ;)).